# Shared object with others classes?

Tags: objective-c, oop, class, share

I just started learning objective c. I have this little problems and questions, hope you guys could help me.

I have a ViewController, I called it: GameViewController.

This GameViewController, will call a model class, "PlayerModel"(NSObject) and this PlayerModel contains "PlayerProfile" object (its a NSObject).

The viewDidLoad in GameViewController will call and initiate model class:

```
playerModel = [[PlayerModel alloc] initWithInt:playerID];
```

Then, in my PlayerModel initWithInt method, I populate PlayerProfile data by fetching the data from online database. I manage to populate the data, but when I want to call it in gameViewController

```
// This is gameViewController.m
....
playerModel.playerProfile.name;
```

But i got this error message: "Property name not found on object of type PlayerProfile"

I NSLog the playerProfile in gameViewController, its "(null)", whereas when I NSLog in the playerModel, it has some values. How do I pass this values and make it universal, so that others classes can make use (set the value) of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "Property name not found," I assume that's a compile error. You probably have failed to `#import PlayerProfile.h` in `GameViewController`.

If `gameViewController` is `nil` in `GameViewController` then either you have not actually initialized it, or `playerModel` is `nil`. Are you sure that you're checking it after `viewDidLoad` actually runs? This can be later than you think.

Comment: You are right, I didnt import PlayerProfile.h in gameviewcontroller. Bcuz I tho I imported PlayerModel, and the PlayerModel import PlayerProfile, so I tho I dont need to import PlayerProfile. Thanks, I learned something today. Anyway, after I do the import, no compilation error, but its still nil. I am not sure if my way of doing correct or not, maybe my program flow is incorrect. What do you normally do, or whats the common practices for such cases?

Comment: I found my answer. To share the class, can use singleton. Example would be here: http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?action=printpage;topic=4090.0